# Unable to SSH into server after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 on GoDaddy

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, putty

I just upgraded my from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and am now unable to SSH into the server. Any ideas? I'm using Putty on Windows 10 to try to connect.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

This question should be on askubuntu, but it is the first result with the `can't ssh after 18.04 upgrade` google/bing search.

Ubuntu 16.04 included OpenSSH 7.2 and Ubuntu 18.04 include OpenSSH 7.6, these releases have [some breaking changes](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6)

The change that seems to break most configs is the removal of `hmac-ripemd160`. Removing it from the config allow to ssh again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and could not SSH back in either. I had two issues that needed to be fixed.

My VPS provider offers another way in with LISH. I noticed SSH errors in the boot up window. What was wrong with the SSH service? Running  `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd –T` gave me a
`Missing privilege separation directory: /var/run/sshd` error.

After following these instructions https://askubuntu.com/questions/53463/ssh-problem-after-update, at least ssh would run. 
`mkdir /var/run/sshd
chmod 0755 /var/run/sshd`

But my key was still not accepted. Then I started tailing the `auth.log`. Lish cut off the line, so this was all I had to go on: `error: userauth_pubkey: could not parse k` . But the first Google hit led me to a report that showed that SSH was failing for key length on Windows boxes. Just on a hunch, I created a new public private key pair and installed it – and Voila, I am in. My old key had been 1024 bits, and was made so long ago that I cannot be sure what encryption method was used in it’s creation. 
https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/855